# ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader/lib!./~/rc-range-slider/lib/Slider/slider.css

Tags: webpack, postcss

I added the rc-range-slider package to my project and started getting the error messages listed in the next paragraph when I tried to compile my react project using Webpack ^2.5.1. The suggested webpack config in the NPM site for this slider is compatible with the previous versions of webpack. The Webpack configuration in the last paragraph below is my attempt to fit it into the new Webpack configuration constraints. But I am getting the following error messages:

Please see a demo at [Github](https://github.com/snystphn/postcss-config/)

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader/lib!./~/rc-range-slider/lib/Slider/slider.css
Module build failed: Error: No PostCSS Config found in: \js\node_modules\rc-range-slider\lib\Slider
    at Error (native)
    at \js\node_modules\postcss-load-config\index.js:51:26
 @ ./~/style-loader!./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader/lib!./~/rc-range-slider/lib/Slider/slider.css 4:14-105 18:2-22:4 19:20-111
 @ ./~/rc-range-slider/lib/Slider/slider.css
 @ ./~/rc-range-slider/lib/Slider/index.js
 @ ./~/rc-range-slider/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/search-component.jsx
 @ ./src/search-component.jsx
 @ ./src/search-container.js
 @ ./src/routes.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server babel-polyfill webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/only-dev-server ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader/lib!./~/rc-tipso/lib/Tipso/BaseTipso/base_tipso.css
Module build failed: Error: No PostCSS Config found in: \js\node_modules\rc-tipso\lib\Tipso\BaseTipso
    at Error (native)
    at \js\node_modules\postcss-load-config\index.js:51:26
 @ ./~/style-loader!./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader/lib!./~/rc-tipso/lib/Tipso/BaseTipso/base_tipso.css 4:14-115 18:2-22:4 19:20-121
 @ ./~/rc-tipso/lib/Tipso/BaseTipso/base_tipso.css
 @ ./~/rc-tipso/lib/Tipso/BaseTipso/index.js
 @ ./~/rc-tipso/lib/Tipso/index.js
 @ ./~/rc-tipso/lib/index.js
 @ ./~/rc-range-slider/lib/Slider/Dragger.js
 @ ./~/rc-range-slider/lib/Slider/index.js
 @ ./~/rc-range-slider/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/search-component.jsx
 @ ./src/search-component.jsx
 @ ./src/search-container.js
 @ ./src/routes.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server babel-polyfill webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/only-dev-server ./src/index.js
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Below is my webpack configuration:

```
var webpack = require( 'webpack' ),
    merge = require( 'lodash/merge' ),
    ExtractTextPlugin = require( 'extract-text-webpack-plugin' ),
    hotModuleReplacement = new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    constants = {
            process:{
                env: {
                    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify( 'development' )
                }
            }
        },
    extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
            allChunks: true,
            disable: constants.process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
            filename: 'public/main.css'
        }),
    getStylesheets = function( ...names ){
            const options = {
                    data: '$env: ' + constants.process.env.NODE_ENV + ';',
                    includePaths: [ 'res/main', 'node_modules' ],
                    sourceMap: true
                  },
                  specifics = {
                    css: {
                        modules: true,
                        importLoaders: 1,
                        localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
                    },
                    postcss: {
                        postcss: () => [ 
                            require( 'postcss-import' )({ 
                                    addDependencyTo: webpack 
                                }),
                            require( 'postcss-url' )(),
                            require( 'postcss-cssnext' )(),
                                  // add your <plugins> here
                                  // ...
                                  // and if you want to compress,
                                  // just use css-loader option that already use cssnano under the hood
                            require( 'postcss-browser-reporter' )(),
                            require( 'postcss-reporter' )()
                        ]
                    },
                  };
            return names.map( 
                    constants.process.env.NODE_ENV ?
                    n => ({ loader: n + '-loader' }) : 
                    n => ({ loader: n + '-loader', options: merge( {}, options, ( specifics[ n ] | {} ))}));
        },
    getJSX = ( ...names ) => 
        names.map( n => ({
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: n + '-loader',
            query: {
                plugins: [ 'transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-runtime' ],
                presets: [ 'latest', 'react', 'airbnb' ]
            }
        }));

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'babel-polyfill',
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src/index.js'
    ],
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        rules:[ 
            ...getJSX( 'react-hot', 'babel' ),
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: extractSass.extract({ 
                    use: getStylesheets( 'style', 'css', 'postcss' ),
                    fallbackLoader: 'style-loader'
                })
            }
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.jsx', '.js', '.json', 'css']
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'main.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: './webpack_html',
        hot: true
    },
    plugins: [ hotModuleReplacement, extractSass, new webpack.DefinePlugin( constants )]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

All magic is in **getStylesheets**.
Here

```
 return names.map( 
                    constants.process.env.NODE_ENV ?
                    n => ({ loader: n + '-loader' }) : 
                    n => ({ loader: n + '-loader', options: merge( {}, options, ( specifics[ n ] | {} ))}));
```

You have

```
constants = {
            process:{
                env: {
                    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify( 'development' )
                }
            }
        }
```

**constants.process.env.NODE_ENV** will be always **true** because only empty string will return false. So you will always map

```
n => ({ loader: n + '-loader' })
```

and you miss one line

> ( specifics[ n ] **|**| {} )

Working example.

```
return names.map(
        constants.process.env.NODE_ENV !== '"development"' ?
                n => ({ loader: n + '-loader' }) :
    n => ({ loader: n + '-loader', options: merge( {}, options, ( specifics[ n ] || {} ))}));
```

Also there is no **postcss-browser-reporter** package in demo

Comment: I created the new file named postcss.config in to my root folder either as an empty file or populated the empty exports object as shown above but the same error message continues to be displayed.

Comment: @000, it is strange. Can you create blank project on github with this error?

Comment: I have created a github repo running only the rc-range-silder react component here https://github.com/snystphn/postcss-config.

Comment: it seems the error is coming from the css modules of the rc-range-slider component. It is producing the following error: `in ./~/css-loader?{"data":"$env: /"development/";","includePaths":["main","node_modules"],"sourceMap":true}!./~/postcss-loader/lib?{"data":"$env: /"development/";","includePaths":["main","node_modules"],"sourceMap":true}!./~/rc-tipso/lib/Tipso/BaseTipso/base_tipso.css
Module build failed: Error: composition is only allowed when selector is single :local class name not in ".tipso-wrapper", ".tipso-wrapper" is weird`

Comment: I will either try to find a more robust react range slider component or simply implement a new one from scratch